# Buiding pandas dataframe from nested data from a mongo db cursor

Tags: python, mongodb, pandas, dataframe

I have nested data from a range of documents that I'd like to put in one Pandas dataframe(with only certain properties). Once I have my cursor I tried looping through the documents and grabbing what I needed.

```
    all_df_real= []

    for doc in cursor_real:
        single_real_df = pd.DataFrame(doc['data']['prices'])
        all_df_real.append(single_real_df) 
    return all_df_real
```

Ideally I wanted to create one big dataframe with all of the data and prices, so that I could then merge it to another dataframe who has rows which are missing values that will come from the `all_df_real` dataframe. The result I get however is a list because I created an empty array to append the `single_real_df` to.

Can someone help me out figure out how to create a dataframe from multiple documents(which I grouped based on a timerange), and only obtaining the nested information?

Initially I queried the database using `find_one`, but ran into problems because of the date range of documents I needed. Or am I going the wrong way about this by creating one dataframe at a time based on the documents from my cursor and trying to make one big dataframe from that...?

**supporting info**
This is what one of my documents look like

```
 {"_id" : ObjectId("1"), 
    "modelRun" : ISODate("2016-11-23T13:04:00.000+0000"), 
    "createdDateTime" : ISODate("2016-11-23T13:30:04.408+0000"), 
    "Type" : "r", 
    "data" : {
        "prices" : [
            {
                "timeStamp" : ISODate("2016-11-23T14:00:00.000+0000"), 
                "value" : 58.48
            }, 
            {
                "timeStamp" : ISODate("2016-11-23T15:00:00.000+0000"), 
                "value" : 55.01
            }, 
            {
                "timeStamp" : ISODate("2016-11-23T16:00:00.000+0000"), 
                "value" : 62.0
            }, 
            {
                "timeStamp" : ISODate("2016-11-23T17:00:00.000+0000"), 
                "value" : 52.92
            } #..etc..
          ]
       }
 }
```

This is how I grabbed my cursor

```
def grab_real_cursor(self, model_dt_till):
    query_real = {'Type': 'r', 'modelRun': {"$gte": model_dt_till, "$lte": model_dt_till + pd.Timedelta(days=1)}}

    cursor = self._collection.find(query_real)
    return cursor
```

**UPDATE**
I tried creating an empty dataframe with just the column names, but now instead of getting a list of all the data like before :

```
[             timeStamp  value
0  2016-11-23 13:00:00  54.98
1  2016-11-23 14:00:00  58.48
2  2016-11-23 15:00:00  55.01
3  2016-11-23 16:00:00  62.00
#.. etc,
,              timeStamp  value
0  2016-11-23 14:00:00  58.48
1  2016-11-23 15:00:00  55.01
2  2016-11-23 16:00:00  62.00
3  2016-11-23 17:00:00  52.92
]

    all_df_real= pd.DataFrame(columns=['timeStamp', 'value'])
```

I know get an empty dataframe

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [timeStamp, value]
Index: []
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still learning Pandas and after updating my question with more attempts I came accross [Concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html). Since

```
all_df_real= []

for doc in cursor_real:
    single_real_df = pd.DataFrame(doc['data']['prices'])
    all_df_real.append(single_real_df) 
return all_df_real
```

returned:

```
[             timeStamp  value
0  2016-11-23 13:00:00  54.98
1  2016-11-23 14:00:00  58.48
2  2016-11-23 15:00:00  55.01
3  2016-11-23 16:00:00  62.00
#.. etc,
,              timeStamp  value
0  2016-11-23 14:00:00  58.48
1  2016-11-23 15:00:00  55.01
2  2016-11-23 16:00:00  62.00
3  2016-11-23 17:00:00  52.92
]
```

A list made up of dataframes, I could just return `result = pd.concat(all_df_real)`.